# Unwanted text in the output when renaming and resetting the counter of figures (for supplementary material)

Tags: floats, counters

I want to rename the figure in the supplementary material (S1, S2 etc...) and therefore also reset the figure counter but an unwanted text appears at the place of the command.

```
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename~S\thefigure}
```

How can I make this "figureFigure SS0" disappear?

Here is the output:

[image]

And here ist he code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor=blue
}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
(figure reference
\ref{example-image-a}). 
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
  \caption{}\label{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{1}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename~S\thefigure}

\section{section 2}
(figure reference
\ref{example-image-b}). 
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{center}
  \caption{}\label{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\fnum@figure` has a `@` in it, you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around it. Also, since you already added `S` in `\thefigure`, there is no need to add it again in `\fnum@figure`. Thus your code should be like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename~\thefigure}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks !! :) @Jinwen